# Directory.Exists returns false when directory is present (works in a standalone console application but not in an ASP project)

Tags: c#, asp.net

As it is described in the title, ASP.NET project code can't find the directory, which exists and can be found by the console C# application. (Disclaimer: I am totally new to .NET and C#).

This displays "true" in the console application, but `Directory.Exists` evaluates to false in the ASP.NET application.

```
string directoryPath = 
                "C:\\Users\\AndreasT\\ProjectDirectory\\ChildDirectory";

Console.WriteLine(Directory.Exists(directoryPath));
```

As I am new to .NET, I cannot give more detailed and accurate information at the moment, so I am looking for any suggestions of what could be wrong (permissions, project setup, etc.)

Comment: What user account is your application's app pool running under?

Comment: @vc74 yes same machine :-)

Comment: @mjwills yes, there was the problem

Comment: I haven't posted a question in stackoverflow in a while, but why the downvote? I know it is a quite generic question, but I don't have .NET experience and I was looking for general guidance (to make sure I am in the right track), not a precise solution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Directory.Exists()` method returns `false` if you dont have minimum read-only permission. It returns `false` in the following conditions.

1. File name with invalid characters
2. Too many characters
3. Failing or missing disk
4. No permission to read the file

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: Condition #4 is probably the culprit in this case

Comment: Let him find out

Comment: It's probably a permission thing. I'll check my IIS settings. Cases 1-3 are covered by the fact that the directory is found by the console application, right?

Comment: @AndreasTasoulas  sure, let me know

Comment: @viveknuna yes, permissions-related. I needed to set the application pool in IIS.

Comment: yeah, up and running now :-)